# point the note OR note the point?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

If I want to thank someone because mntioned a good subject, which one would be the best and why?

> 1. Thanks for **pointig great note**.
> 2. Thanks for **noting great point**.

Or are these basically the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, "**thanks for making a great point**." Neither option you mention seems appropriate.

You also need the indefinite article before *great*: "Thanks for making great point" would only be said by a non-native speaker.

"Pointing a note" does not make much sense. "Noting a point" is understandable, but I would recommend saying, "making a point."